# Process output only becomes available after the process has finished

Tags: java, swing, runnable

I have a Runnable that reads Console output from an externally called exe (see below) and writes it to both a log file and a JTextArea.

But my Runnable doesn't show the Console output in the JTextArea until the exe completely finishes. How do I get it to print Console output as it happens?

Short Concise Code Example below:

//Main

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    public static int maxX, maxY;

    public static JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 60);//For LOG display window

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException
    {   
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {

        this.setTitle("Example");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //MAIN Panel
        final JPanel main = new JPanel();

        JButton RunButton = button.run(main);
        main.add(RunButton);

        Container container = getContentPane();


        container.add(main);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

//Button Action Listener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;


public class button {

    public static JButton run( final JPanel parent ) {
        JButton RunButton = new JButton();      
        RunButton.setText("Start!");

        RunButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event)
            {
                try
                {

                    //Set up LOG Display    
                    JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null, "Working...");
                    JPanel temp_panel = new JPanel();
                    temp_panel.add(new JScrollPane(Example.ta));
                    dialog.getContentPane().add(temp_panel);
                    dialog.pack();
                    dialog.setVisible(true);

                    //Build the Command
                    ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
                    command.add("ping");
                    command.add("127.0.0.1");

                    //Start the process
                    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();

                    //Starts LOG display capture in separate thread 
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new execute(p));

                    //Wait for call to complete
                    p.waitFor();
                }
                catch(Exception err)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( parent, "Error Executing Run!", "Warning", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );  
                }

            }//end ActionPerformed
        });
        return RunButton;
    }
}
```

//Runnable

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class execute implements Runnable {  
    String line;
    Process p; 

    public execute ( Process process ) {
        p = process;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            //Read Process Stream Output and write to LOG file
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while ( (line = is.readLine()) != null ) {
                Example.ta.append(line + "\n");
            }   
            System.out.flush();     
        } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }  

    }
}
```

Comment: The output is probably buffered by the OS.

Comment: There's no JTextArea usage in the posted code ^)

Comment: Please rephrase the subject: your `Runnable` does indeed run in a separate thread.

Comment: As of the problem, what does `PartGen.ta.append(line + "\n")` do?

Comment: sidenote: In Java classes should always be capitalized.

Comment: As of the problem, what does PartGen.ta.append(line + "\n") do? The java file PartGen defines a JTextArea ta. that is all that is happening there. you can replace PartGen.ta with JTextArea ta.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without Swing at all? That is, http://sscce.org/ will be helpful.

Comment: Putting together SSCCE right now. I'll have it posted in about an hour or so.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that the thread wasn't capturing the data, it was the JTextArea just not refreshing. `repaint()`, `revalidate()`, and `updateUI()` did not refresh the JTextArea, but the following did:

```
Example.ta.update(Example.ta.getGraphics());
```

Comment: then something is seriously wrong ... that's _never_ needed if everything else is well

Comment: Kleopatra, the SCCE that I provided above, worked for you. It did not work on my machines until I added that code. If there is a problem with my code, it would be present in the SCCE above. The fact that it worked for you without that, tells me it has to do with something other than my code.

Comment: never said that anything worked for me (in fact, didn't even try to) You had been randomly trying api. You accidentially hit something that _seems_ to work for you _now_ - but it's wrong (really!) to call either update(Graphics) or getGraphics() in Swing. If it seems to be needed, the real error is elsewhere, you're just smearing color on it instead of digging, finding and fixing the core issue. Be happy now, as it will strike back sooner or later ;-)

Comment: ah, ok. I will dig deeper then. *puts on miners hat and grabs canary cage*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's because you don't respect [Swing's threading policy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). All accesses to swing components must be done in the event dispatch thread. Your runnable should thus use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the text area in the EDT, rather than in your separate thread.

EDIT : as alf mentions in his comment: `JTextArea.append` is thread-safe, so it's not absolutely needed here. I would still do it, though, because if the append to a text area was replaced or complemented by any other Swing interaction, it wouldn't be thread-safe anymore.

It could also be that the external process doesn't send any newline character, which makes `readLine` block until one is found or the end of communication is reached.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're wrong: `public void append(String str)` —
***This method is thread safe,*** although most Swing methods are not. Please see Threads and Swing for more information. (as per http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)

Comment: I bet the problem is due to buffering, but cannot prove it. Swing is of no relevance here.

Comment: @alf don't believe everything that's written ;-) AFAIR, there are reasonable doubts that the methods of textComponents which are documented as thread safe actually _are_ so. Better err on the safe side and not rely on it

Answer (score 3):

Just to help the miner - below's a complete minimalistic (left out everything not absolutely necessary) example that indeed works in my context: each line appears in the textArea as read. It's basically using the SwingWorker as suggested by Justin and re-arranged thingies a bit for clarity.

```
public class ProcessExample {

    public static class ProcessWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private JTextArea ta;
        private List<String> process;

        public ProcessWorker(List<String> command, JTextArea ta) {
            this.process = command;
            this.ta = ta;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(process).start();
            // Read Process Stream Output and write to LOG file
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(line);
            }
            is.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String string : chunks) {
                ta.append(string + "\n");
            }
        }

    }

    private void startProcess(JTextArea ta) {
        ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("ping");
        command.add("127.0.0.1");
        new ProcessWorker(command, ta).execute();
    }

    private JComponent getContent() {
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 60);
        main.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        Action action = new AbstractAction("Start!") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startProcess(ta);
            }
        };
        main.add(new JButton(action), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return main;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.add(new ProcessExample().getContent());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the same logic with a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) instead.  You can extend this class, instead of implementing runnable.  It could take your Text area as a paramater, and you can publish the data, without having to deal with the SwingUtils.invokeLater, which is guiltily easier...

Try:

```
public class execute extends javax.swing.SwingWorker {  
      String line;
      Process p; 
      JTextArea jta;

      File f = new File( properties.prop.getProperty( "LOG_FILE_DIR" ) + "\\PartGen.log");

      public execute ( Process process , JTextArea jta ) {
          p = process;
          this.jta = jta;
      }

      //implements a method in the swingworker
      public void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //Read Process Stream Output and write to LOG file
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while ( (line = is.readLine()) != null ) {
            osfile.writeline(line, f);
            publish(new String(line + "\n"));
        }   
        System.out.flush();  
        return null; 
  }
  //This will happen on the UI Thread.
  public void process(List lines){
      for(Object o : lines){
         jta.append((String)o);
      }
  }

  public void done(){
     try{
        get();
        //You will get here if everything was OK.  So show a popup or something to signal done.
     }catch(Exception ex){
         //this is where your IO Exception will surface, should you have one.
     }
  }
}
```

Also, in your calling code, which I assume is in your ui somewhere:

```
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
    execute ex = new execute( p , yourTextArea);
    ex.execute();
```

I didnt attempt to compile this, so you may have to check against the API, but hopefully it will give you a gist of what to do.

Comment: changed to Runnable run = new execute(p); SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new execute(p)); and it still has same results.

Comment: I just tried this example too. It doesn't show the Console output until the process ends. Same problem.

Comment: I tested this code with the "ping" command on windows... which does work.  It may be as alf suggested and be an issue with buffering...

Comment: If it is a buffering issue with windows, and it works on your machine, there must be a setting for it. I tried the example code with the "ping" that I posted on Windows 7 (64-bit) machine and a Windows XP (32-bit) machine with the same results. I tried messing with the buffering, but that option only affects command history.

Comment: Let me clarify. the code works in that it prints the pings to the JTextArea, but not until after all of the pings have completed. (i.e. the program has finished) I need it to print the output as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is with the waitFor:

```
p.waitFor();
```

This causes the Button Action Listener to wait on that point until the process is completed.