# VM freeze on checking ping from a server

Tags: java, swing, virtual-machine, ping, bluej

I am trying to code a program that would check ping from league of legends servers. I used the command prompt ping command to ping the server in the method. But when I click on my button that should call the method, the virtual machine freezes while the system.print.out.ln prints out the ping number. I am trying to make the ping display on the panel not the terminal window. Kindly suggest.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Panel03 extends JPanel
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;

    public Panel03()
    {
        JButton ping = new JButton("ping");
        ping.addActionListener(new Listener1());
        add(ping);

        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit"); 
        quitButton.addActionListener(new Listener());
        add(quitButton);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label1= new JLabel ("0.0");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        label1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        add(label1);

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     * 
     * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
     * @return     the sum of x and y 
     */
    private class Listener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private class Listener1 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x)
        {

            try
            {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process pr = rt.exec("ping riot.ca -t");

                BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                String line=null;

                while((line=input.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    label1.setText(line);
                }

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                //System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Maybe you have an infinite loop.

Comment: _Don't_ run malformed command lines on the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process output only becomes available after the process has finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082041/process-output-only-becomes-available-after-the-process-has-finished)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082041/process-output-only-becomes-available-after-the-process-has-finished

Answer (score 0):

`input.readLine()` will never be `null` because `ping host -t` never stops `ping`ing, and therefore the input will loop forever. Removing `-t`, which will cause a few outputs to appear.

If you are using an IDE, then I recommend experimenting with just that by setting a breakpoint and debugging the loop. You'll notice that it never stops, which will cause the application to appear to freeze.