# How to create another "version" of process()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I'm using [MessageConsole.java](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) to redirect standard output stream to a text pane. After finishing it, I thought it would be nice to redirect the error stream as well. To do so, I added another buffered reader to a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185272/4005742) answer. Next is where my problem is - I need another "version" of the `process()` method which prints to `System.err` instead of `System.out`. I tried Googling it, but my results were nill. How would I add in another version of a Overridden method that requires specific arguments? The code might look something like the second example.

My current code

```
class ConsoleThread extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    String command;

    ConsoleThread(String cmd) {
        command = cmd;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {


            Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader es = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getErrorStream()));

            String outputLine;
            String errorLine;

            while ((outputLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(outputLine);
            }

            while ((errorLine = es.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(errorLine);
            }

            is.close();

            return null;

    }



    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunk) {
        for (String string : chunk) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }


}
```

What the answer might look like (a snippet of code is worth a thousand words)

```
class ConsoleThread extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    String command;

    ConsoleThread(String cmd) {
        command = cmd;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {


            Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader es = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getErrorStream()));

            String outputLine;
            String errorLine;

            while ((outputLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(outputLine);
            }

            while ((errorLine = es.readLine()) != null) {
                publish2(errorLine);
            }

            is.close();

            return null;

    }



    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunk) {
        for (String string : chunk) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process2(List<String> chunk) {
        for (String string : chunk) {
            System.err.println(string);
        }
    }


}
```

Where `process2()` would be treated like the original `process()`.

To be clear, the current code works but sends any error messages to the output stream rather than the error stream. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198627/4005742))

Comment: It may not answer the question, but: I'd recommend you to consider creating a dedicated infrastructure for that, and *not* relying on the message console class. The linked answer already shows how to write to a text area, you could use this with minor modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "another version of Process" at all. All you need are two new threads, one for each Stream, both the InputStream and the ErrorStream. Create two Runnables, put the while loops in those Runnables, pass your Streams into them, and run the Runnables in their own threads.

You could wrap the messages that you wish to publish in a wrapper object that identifies the stream origin of the method, allowing you to use the same publish/process pair, or you could use other notification methods such as PropertyChangeListeners and PropertyChangeSupport.

---

For what it's worth, I've used this code in previous attempts to read error and output streams:

enum GobblerType.java

```
public enum GobblerType {
   ERROR, OUTPUT
}
```

class StreamGobbler.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {

   private InputStream is;
   private GobblerType type;
   private OutputStream os;

   public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, GobblerType type) {
      this(is, type, null);
   }

   public GobblerType getType() {
      return type;
   }

   public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, GobblerType type, OutputStream redirect) {
      this.is = is;
      this.type = type;
      this.os = redirect;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         PrintWriter pw = null;
         if (os != null) {
            pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
         }
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
         String line = null;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (pw != null) {
               pw.println(line);
            }
            // System.out.println(type + "> " + line);
         }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

class TextAreaOutputStream.java  -- I have most doubts about this one

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {

   private final JTextArea textArea;
   private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   private String title;

   public TextAreaOutputStream(final JTextArea textArea, String title) {
      this.textArea = textArea;
      this.title = title;
      sb.append(title + "> ");
   }

   @Override
   public void flush() {
   }

   @Override
   public void close() {
   }

   @Override
   public void write(int b) throws IOException {

      if (b == '\r')
         return;

      if (b == '\n') {
         final String text = sb.toString() + "\n";
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               textArea.append(text);
            }
         });
         sb.setLength(0);
         sb.append(title + "> ");

         return;
      }

      sb.append((char) b);
   }
}
```

None of this is professional code, just junk I've played with.

Comment: I have thought about this, but I wanted to see if there was another way.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: "another way"? What do you mean, and why would you want to do this? You could wrap the messages you wish to publish in a wrapper object that identifies the origin of the method, allowing you to use the same publish/process pair, or you could use other notification methods such as PropertyChangeListeners and PropertyChangeSupport.

Comment: Because I enjoy exploring all possible methods of doing something. It's one of the ways I learn.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: fine, I still have no idea what you mean, but if it pleases you, go for it.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: Please see edit to answer. Some code I've played with to try to solve similar problems.